# How to stop a function containing another function from the contained function in javascript?

Tags: javascript, function, return

Sorry for the title, but I did not found a simple one.
I have a long function: function testa().
Running this function I call several times another one: function testb().
When function testb() returns "false", I would like to stop function testa() too before the end of the function.
Thank you for helping ;)

Here is an example:

```
function testb(){
if (blabla.test(val)) { 
    return true;           
}
else {
    return false;
}


function testa(){
blabla
blabla
function testb()// if function testb() return false, stop function testa() here, else continue function testa()
blabla
blabla
blabla
blabla
blabla
function testb() // if function testb() return false, stop function testa() here, else continue function testa()
blabla
blabla
blabla
function testb()// if function testb() return false, stop function testa() here, else continue function testa()
blabla
blabla
blabla

return
}
```

Comment: This is what exceptions are for. Or otherwise just do `if (testb()) return;` whenever you are calling it and want to stop depending on the result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply return from function testa so that further code is not executed.

```
function testb(){
if (blabla.test(val)) { 
    return true;           
}
else {
    return false;
}

function testa(){
blabla;
blabla;
if(!testb()) {
   return;
}
blabla;//continue here
blabla;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can nest them in the testa if statement, and use `break;` to stop the function

EDIT

By that I meant like this:

```
if(!testb){
break;
}
```

Comment: You can only `break` from loops (or labelled blocks), not from functions.

Answer (score 1):

You can use "return" to end function:

```js
function testa(){
  bla
  bla

  if (!testb()) return;
  
  bla
  bla

  if (!testb()) return;

  bla

}
```